# Read XML file parse it into a class list

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2013

This is the code that I've used to write the data from the List to the XML file:

```
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(@"animals.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var dcsw = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Animal>));
                XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(f);

                try
                {
                    dcsw.WriteObject(f, animalList);
                    writer.Close();
                    f.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

This is an example of my XML file:

```
<ArrayOfAnimal xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter">
<Animal i:type="Cat">
<ChipRegistrationNumber>12346</ChipRegistrationNumber>
<DateOfBirth>
<date>1234-11-11T00:00:00</date>
</DateOfBirth>
<IsReserved>false</IsReserved>
<Name>Yoshi</Name>
<BadHabits>Scratches</BadHabits>
<Price>51</Price>
</Animal>

<Animal i:type="Dog">
<ChipRegistrationNumber>12347</ChipRegistrationNumber>
<DateOfBirth>
<date>1234-11-11T00:00:00</date>
</DateOfBirth>
<IsReserved>false</IsReserved>
<Name>Sonic</Name>
<LastWalkDate>
<date>1234-11-11T00:00:00</date>
</LastWalkDate>
<Price>200</Price>
</Animal>
</ArrayOfAnimal>
```

As you can see, Cat has a a node called "BadHabits" and Dog has a different one called "LastWalkDate".

"Cat" and "Dog" inherit from the class Animal.

I've seen many examples of parsing strings to a List.. That's quite do-able.. but my list has different types like a custom date class

Example of an instance of Animal:

```
SimpleDate date1 = new SimpleDate(11, 11, 1234);
Animal cat1 = new Cat("12346", date1, "Yoshi", "Scratches");
```

How am I able to parse all the cats and dogs from the XML file in a `List<Animal>`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your class related to your XML file.
Generated with [this tools](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

EDIT : you have an invalid XML near from the "Price" element : `<Price>51</rice>`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="DateOfBirth", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
    public class DateOfBirth {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="date", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Animal", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
    public class Animal {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ChipRegistrationNumber", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string ChipRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DateOfBirth", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public DateOfBirth DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="IsReserved", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string IsReserved { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Name", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="BadHabits", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string BadHabits { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Price", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="LastWalkDate", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public LastWalkDate LastWalkDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="LastWalkDate", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
    public class LastWalkDate {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="date", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="ArrayOfAnimal", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
    public class ArrayOfAnimal {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Animal", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AnimalShelter")]
        public List<Animal> Animal { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="i", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string I { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, my bad.. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use something like this:

```
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(<pathtoxml>, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Animal>));
                XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(f, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

                List<Animal> listfromxml = (List<Animal>)dcs.ReadObject(reader);
            }
```